# Open an Activity on top of Map activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to open two activities simultaneously, one of them is an Android intent for launching route on Google maps.

For this I used, PendingIntent.getActivities. Using this method it looks whenever I launch more than one activity the data doesn't gets delivered to Android map activity.

As a workaround for this I created another Activity and from there I am launching these two activities, using startActivity twice.

This starts both of them, but not in the same required sequence, the map activity is always on top, while the second one comes to front when I press the back and finish the Map, even using delayed launch of the other activity does not creates any effect.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

Finally I used a work around, and launched the activity using pending intent, and it's working now.